# how to avoid chrome from showing a white bar at bottom left of page when page load?

Tags: google-chrome

look at the white bar at the bottom left of the picture, is there any way to get rid of that?

**Notice**: I don't want to use chrome theme

[image: google chrome white bar on loading]

Comment: This is already answered here: [Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @Chokoladekiks in such cases you can flag the question as a duplicate.